# Why does OneDrive display smaller folder size than local?

Tags: onedrive

On OneDrive, I saw that the folders and files I uploaded were 374GB. When I ran `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File folder_name | Measure-Object -Property Length -sum` on Powershell, it gave me 402GB. I verified everything was there. Is this discrepancy normal?

Comment: is the 402GB value that you are getting reported as 402,000,000,000?

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive reports actual size of objects using their binary size. So, 374GB on OneDrive is equivalent to 401579442176 actual bytes in decimal format.

A true GB is 2^30 bytes

Comment: That's the size I'm getting in Powershell, but why? I don't get the math and this is rather new to me...I thought 1 GB was 1000000000 bytes.